# How to retrieve the last 15 mins SMSSubscriptionLog records based on OptInDate using SQL Query?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

I have a scenario that i need to retrieve the last 15 mins SMSSubscriptionLog (data view) created/updated records based on OptInDate using SQL Query. I will store the results in the created DE.

If we don't have these filters, please suggest alternative solutions with examples.

Thanks,
Venkat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [DATEDIFF()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datediff.asp) SQL function, which returns the difference between two dates (current date and the date when the event occurred), and in your case, the difference needs to be defined in minutes:

```
SELECT *
FROM _SMSSubscriptionLog
WHERE DateDiff(minute, OptInDate, GETDATE()) < 15
```

Comment: Thanks zuzannamj. This query is working, one small correction that we have to use < instead of > symbol.

Comment: Ahhh yes my bad, let me correct it